# Scrollview in a Scrollview with "scroll transfer" using React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am trying to have a scrollview in a scrollview, but I can't find a way to make it work the way I would like it to be.

I would like to have something pretty similar to what the app Periscope has: https://youtu.be/FiFCNakULfY

The user starts to scroll, the outside scrollview scrolls, then when it reaches the top, the velocity is transferred to the inside scrollview.

I tried a few different things, using PanResponder as well as 2 ScrollView components but I can't make it to the same result.

The PanResponder doesn't have this "bounce" effect when it reaches the top. Not sure how to implement that.

The ScrollView doesn't provide the velocity, and even if I calculate it manually, you can't really use `scrollTo` with a velocity.

So I'm wondering if there is any way this could be possible to build with React Native?

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I'm looking to do something similar.

Comment: I had to build it myself, with a pan responder inside a pan responder. The right pan responder takes the grant depending on the direction of the movement

Comment: @alexmngn would you be willing to post a simplified version of your code?